# Refactoring Object Oriented PHP Codes - Changes Variables, Classes, File Names, etc

Tags: php, refactoring

I have an application which is written in Object Oriented PHP. The main project folder called 'applepie' which has various sub-folders including 'Admin', 'System', 'Template', etc. In many instances class names and their filenames are similar. For example, `class admin_NewUsers {...}` is in `NewUsers.php` file. My goal is to rename/refactor the name of classes or variables in `applepie` folder so that all classes and variables with their filenames change in a single action. For example, by changing NewUsers to AwesomeUsers, `class admin_AwesomeUsers {...}` and `AwesomeUsers.php` get generated instantly. Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: PHP can't do that itself, but you can use any popular IDE to archieve it

Comment: @PatrickSafarov, Hi Patrick. I have PHPStrom and ZendStudio installed on my Mac. Can I rename the classes or variables with filenames in 'ApplePie' project (not in a single) using these IDEs?

Comment: Yes, phpstorm definitely can do that

Comment: @PatrickSafarov, I could refactor the folder names using PHPStorm. Is it the same process for classes changes?

Comment: You can rename class in one place, and IDE will change it everywhere, but after you have to rename the file with the class manually